# Silverlight player centered viewport example

Tags: game-mechanics, silverlight

I am new to game development and i want to use silverlight for it.
First of all i want to learn the logic of player centered gameplay. 
Something like this;

Player character moves in large scaled map but player can see only the viewport (centered on player) like on 3000x3000 px map with 400x400 viewport

what do i need to achive this?
Is there a code example or any bookthat contains this?
Do i need to use a map generator? (so when player moves it replaces titles according to matrix text file etc)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points you should take care of while implementing a game using Silverlight:

1. Silverlight is not a game engine, nor it is a technology primarily targeting game development (like XNA, for example). You will need to implement more things on your own. the most classical example here is the implementation of the [game loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming) -- it is possible in Silverlight using `Dispatcher` and `Timer`, but this can be tricky (due to multi-threading etc). Just [google](http://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1SKPL_enDE448DE448&aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=silverlight%20game%20loop) for "Silverlight Game Loop", there are plenty of good tutorials on that topic.
2. I would generally recommend to read some gamedev tutorial for Silverlight. You will find a plenty of links in [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/173418.aspx/1). Especially this link to a Silverlight [platform tutorial](http://www.laumania.net/post/Porting-XNA-starter-kit-Platformere2809d-to-Silverlight-%28SilverSprite%29.aspx) and starter kit (ported from XNA) can be helpful for you.
3. And now to your question! :) You will probably need to use the `ScrollViewer` [component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) from Silverlight core components and manipulate the `ViewPort` properties to reach the scrolling and centering in your application. Just google for "sliding with ScrollViewer" and you'll find many ways how to implement this behaviour.

Comment: These points are fairly obsolete with the releast of Silverlight 5, which has an XNA-like interface and a 3D engine that may work very well for gaming.

Comment: @JeremyLikness: I don't see what points have become obsolete with SL5. I haven't worked with it yet (it is just released), maybe I missed something?